# Backbone.js - navigating to a route after the "click" event on a view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My "view" is set up as below. simple.

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName : "li",

  events : {
    "click" : "display"
  },

  display : function() {
    //app.navigate('item'); // take me to my route!
  }
});
```

And I have my router

```
var App = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "" : "index",
    "item" : "view_item"
  },

  index: function() {
    alert('hi!');
  },

  view_item: function() {
    alert('bye!');
  }
});

app = new App();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Now, when I click on ItemView, it should run "display" method and I want the display method to take me to the route I specified in routes "item".

Is this possible? I thought "navigate" function will work, but it doesn't. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
 display : function() {
    app.navigate('item', true);
  }
```

You need the second parameter set to true.

From the Backbone documentation:

> navigaterouter.navigate(fragment, [triggerRoute]) 
>   Whenever you reach a point in your application that you'd like to save as a URL, call navigate in order to update the URL. If you wish to also call the route function, pass triggerRoute.

Comment: An alternative way to do the same and corresponding with the backbone docs: `app.navigate('item', { trigger: true });`

Comment: If you don't have the `app` Router in scope, you can use `Backbone.history.navigate(url, options)`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it directly from html, if you're using "< a >" tag.

example:

```
<a href="#item">Show Itens</a>
```

It also works, I prefer this way when of course is possible.